# Comparison script diffrent files

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to write a script that compares a bunch of files based on a search word, in this case i searched for  106, then i want the code to match the words from file 1 to the words in file 2 and print a list with the ones that dont match.

For example in file A i have this line

**106_LB01_GP61_HAL;LB01;10892;DIGITAL;0;0;0;0;;;Smutsigt tilluftsfilter;;**

and in file B i have

**"Prefix": "106_LB01_GP61",**

those lines match and then i want it to ignore that tag

when the script find lines that dont match etc when a tag in file A cant fint its buddy in file B i want it to write those tags to a file,

for example:

Total unused tags:1

- 106_LB01_GP61

right now i am stuc at making it read to diffrent files at the same time

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Import os module
import os

# Ask the user to enter string to search
search_path = (".")
file_type = (".wpp")
search_str = input("Enter searchword: ")
resultsFile = "results.csv" 
file_name = ("results.csv")

# Append a directory separator if not already present
if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\") ): 
        search_path = search_path + "/"
                                                          
# If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
if not os.path.exists(search_path):
        search_path ="."
0
# Repeat for each file in the directory  
for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

   # Apply file type filter   
   if fname.endswith(file_type):


        # Open file for reading
        fo = open(search_path + fname)

        # Read the first line from the file
        line = fo.readline()

        # Initialize counter for line number
        line_no = 1

        # Loop until EOF
        wf = open(search_path + resultsFile, 'a')
        while line != '' :
                # Search for string in line
                index = line.find(search_str)
                if ( index != -1) :
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
                wf.write(line + "  ")
                # Read next line
                line = fo.readline()  
                # Increment line counter
                line_no += 1
        
        # Close the files
        fo.close()

def check_if_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    """ Check if any line in the file contains given string """
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            if string_to_search in line:
                return True
    return False

def check_if_string_in_file(file_name2, string_to_search):
    """ Check if any line in the file contains given string """
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name2, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            if string_to_search in line:
                return True
    return False


def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
    along with line numbers"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            # For each line, check if line contains the string
            line_number += 1
            if string_to_search in line:
                # If yes, then add the line number & line as a tuple in the list
                list_of_results.append((line_number, line.rstrip()))
    # Return list of tuples containing line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results

   

def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    """Get line from the file along with line numbers, which contains any string from the list"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    # If any string is found in line, then append that line along with line number in list
                    list_of_results.append((string_to_search, line_number, line.rstrip()))
    # Return list of tuples containing matched string, line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results



def main():
    print('*** Loading *** ')
    matched_lines = search_string_in_file(file_name, search_str)

    for elem in matched_lines:
        print('Line Number = ', elem[0], ' :: Line = ', elem[1])

    # search for given strings in the file 'sample.txt'
    matched_lines = search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, [search_str])
    print('*** Checking if',  [search_str], 'exists in a file *** ')
    print('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
      # Check if string 'is' is found in file 'sample.txt'
    if check_if_string_in_file(file_name, search_str):
        print('Yes, string found in file')
    else:
        print('String not found in file')

       
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.